# Instagram API + Fetch newly uploaded photo of user

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm building an application basing on Instagram API,

Is there a way to detect if a user has uploaded a new photo? I've seen this link http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/ , but looks like it is not returning the user's image url. It only returns this data

```
 {
        "subscription_id": "1",
        "object": "user",
        "object_id": "1234",
        "changed_aspect": "media",
        "time": 1297286541
 },
```

As you can see there's no URL of the photo of the user.

Maybe i'm just not understanding the Instagram API well, or maybe I am correct. Can someone give me an idea how this really works or if getting the newly uploaded photo of the user possible.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Instagram API real time updates only alert you that a new media object was posted for one of your subscriptions. It is up to you to then decide what to do with that information.

So for your example with the user subscription, you would receive and update from Instagram that the user you have subscribed to has added a new media object. You then would need to use another Instagram endpoint to search for media by that user.